# Изобел(ь) - как возникла такая транскрипция имени?

Tags: ономастика, транскрипция

См. [**Isobel Cooper**](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1693186-izobel-kak-voznikla-takaja-transkripcija-imeni-isobel-cooper.html).

Известные [Изобели](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isobel):

```
Isobel of Huntingdon (1199-1251), Scottish royalty
Isobel Baillie (1895-1983), Scottish operatic soprano
Isobel Barnett (1918-1980), British radio and television personality
Isobel Buchanan (born 1954), Scottish operatic soprano
Isobel Campbell (born 1976), Scottish singer, formerly with Belle and Sebastian
Isobel Gowdie, Scottish woman who was tried for witchcraft in 1662
Isobel Elsom (1893-1981), English actress
Isobel Joyce (born 1983), Irish cricketer
Isobel Miller Kuhn (1901-1957), Canadian missionary
Isobel Lennart (1915-1971), American screenwriter and playwright
Isobel Redmond (born 1953), Australian politician
```

Comment: В русском принята транслитерация, по-видимому.  Или Вы про английскую транскрипцию спрашиваете?

Comment: Английская транскрипция восходит к Шотландской, похоже.

Comment: Я про Лизаньку: откудова "о"-то? Изабе́лла (англ. Isabel(le)) — французская, испанская и португальская форма имени Елизавета.

Comment: Изабелла – это ставшая самостоятельной испанская форма библейского имени Иезавель, что означает "Почитающая Бога". (с)

Comment: Непонятен вопрос.  Изобель Купер так назвали её родители. Если Вас интересует, откуда "o" в Шотландском варианте, то как **мы**-то можем помочь в форуме по *русскому языку*?

Comment: Если Вы попробуете погуглить ея как ИзОбель, Вам насыплют кучку ИзАбелей Купер... Вполне на русском. По ссылке в вопросе она у меня замечательно поёт теноровую арию; я хотела бы о ней поговорить - по-русски! Так как ея в русском транскрибировать?

Comment: "1975 - Родилась ИЗЗИ (Izzy), наст. имя Изабель Купер (Isobel Cooper), английская оперная/поп-певица (сопрано)".

Comment: Её сценическое имя "Izzy", а не "Isobel".  Пробовали?  http://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B7%D0%B8+%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80

Comment: Откуда эта цитата? "наст имя..."

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30225/discussion-between-galina-avanesova-and-victor-bazarov).

Comment: Давайте, Галина, вы поправьте Ваш вопрос, чтобы было понятно, о чём вы хотите узнать.  А то я всё гадаю, а толку мало.

Comment: А как и на что нужно поправить вопрос? Почему по-аглицки можно с "о", а по-русски нужно с "а"?